# Compile mlmodel on a linux server

Tags: ios, coreml

I'm wondering if there is a solution out there to compile a .mlmodel to a .mlmodelc on a linux server ?

I know this can be done with

```
xcrun coremlcompiler compile /path/to/MyModel.mlmodel /path/to/
```

But xcrun isn't available for linux. What would be the best solution ? Am I forced to build it in-app ?

```
let compiledModelUrl = try? MLModel.compileModel(at: destinationFileUrl)
```

Should I use an OSX server just for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to do this? So you can run the Core ML model from Swift on Linux, or for some other reason?

If you want to run Core ML models from Swift on Linux, you're out of luck, as Core ML is a macOS/iOS-only framework.

However, you may want to check out NNVM, a compiler that can convert Core ML model files into code that runs on CUDA, OpenCL, etc.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/introducing-nnvm-compiler-a-new-open-end-to-end-compiler-for-ai-frameworks/

Comment: To avoid having to download a .mlmodel then compile it in-app. Compiling it remotely would take server-time instead of app-time and is less error-prone

Comment: So you're looking for some automated solution? Normally you'd just add the (updated) .mlmodel file to your Xcode project and build the app, or as you say using `xcrun coremlcompiler` on the command line. This typically isn't something you do often. Most developers will do this as part of their app's normal release cycle.

Comment: Downloading .mlmodel and compiling it in-app avoid to re-submit an app to Apple every time a change is made to the model. Compiling it on a server would be a plus :) But I doubt this is possible for now.